# /dev/mapper/vg00-var maxing out

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory, tmp

Over the past few years we have had multiple Linux servers have the same problem time and time again: our `/dev/mapper/vg00-var` folder maxes out at 100%, which means all sites on the server die.

We have found a temporary solution for this which is to increase the size of this `var` folder. However, even though we keep increasing the size of this folder, it keeps filling up, and we have had one server maxing out even though the folder size is very large.

Is there a way of emptying this folder, as it is eating into our server capacity regularly? Also what are the files that are being saved here? are they needed? is there a way of preventing so much data getting stored here?

We are running a CMS site on the server called [concrete5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need an audit of the `/var` folder at first.

If you're the system admin it is generally not a good idea to just install a software and see what happens. *Know/learn* what a software does to the filesystem, too. There are also [monitoring tools](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2012/03/22/linux-monitoring-tools/) that prevent such big surprises as the `/var` folder filled up.

### System logs

A common reason for free space to shrink on the `/var` folder is logs. There is a package, `logrotate`, which rotates logs and keeps the log space from growing disproportionately. On Debian-based most if not all system packages that use logs are logrotate-aware, i.e. they come with predefined sets of rules to recycle their log files.

### Documents in a CMS

If it's a CMS that uses `/var/www` as its storage space, you'll have to check on your own what causes the storage space to increase. You'll need to monitor it daily at least (see above monitoring tools).

Are there multimedia files in your CMS? Have people been told what to do about their files? Do they know how to manage the size of their documents? Is publishing public? Is it moderated?

All these questions have an impact on what you have to do to prevent anarchic growth.

### Intruders

If it's a public web server, it's not uncommon to see it compromised although I'm not sure web servers get hogged up like this. In general cyber-attacks I've ever witnessed were limited to turning a server into a [botnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet) member and a spam bot but such a disastrous effect cannot be excluded either.

---

If you can't afford installing a complex monitoring solution, you'll have at least to check the used space:

```
du -hsx /var/www/*

-h for a human-readable report
-s for a brief summary of all files and subfolders
-x to stay on the same volume (in case other mounts under exist `/var/www`)
```

> Also what are the files that are being saved here?
>
> are they needed?

These are questions you'll have to find the answer yourself or at least with the help of the system administrator. Most of all you'll have to identify what causes such a growth before even thinking of deleting files. That's why constant, regular monitoring is best.